# Is there any way to send the Email notification using asp.net without using credentials?

Tags: asp.net, email

I have this code to send email notification in my page.

```
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com"); 
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com"); 
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to); 
message.Subject = "Error Occred in the application:"; 
message.Body = ex.Message; 
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587); 
client.EnableSsl = true; 
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
```

Is there any other way we have without giving credentials to send the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some workarounds mentioned [here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/257442-Without-credentials-how-send-mail-using-asp-net-with-c.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Only on servers that allow anonymous sending, which Gmail doesn't.

Comment: Hmm.. can I use my domain server for sending an email without any credentials? thanks

Comment: Here are instructions on allowing anonymous outbound mail on your Exchange virtual SMTP server: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124305(EXCHG.65).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you have an open mail relay that doesn't require credentials, then you don't need to supply them.

Comment: Thanks Jason,suppose if I am using intranet application for my project..so shell i use my official EmailID without credentilas?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this code spinet for that,

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
MailAddress SendFrom = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
MailAddress SendTo = new MailAddress(txtTo.Text);

MailMessage MyMessage = new MailMessage(SendFrom, SendTo);

MyMessage.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
MyMessage.Body = txtBody.Text;

Attachment attachFile = new Attachment(txtAttachmentPath.Text);
MyMessage.Attachments.Add(attachFile);

SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(txtSMTPServer.Text);
emailClient.Send(MyMessage);

litStatus.Text = "Message Sent";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
litStatus.Text=ex.ToString();
}
}
```

i hope this will be helpful.